# Why Word2Vec function returns me a lot of 0.99 values

Tags: python, gensim, word2vec

I'm trying to apply a word2vec model on a review dataset. First of all I apply the preprocessing to the dataset:

```
df=df.text.apply(gensim.utils.simple_preprocess)
```

and this is the dataset that I get:

```
0       [understand, location, low, score, look, mcdon...
3       [listen, it, morning, tired, maybe, hangry, ma...
6       [super, cool, bathroom, door, open, foot, nugg...
19      [cant, find, better, mcdonalds, know, getting,...
27      [night, went, mcdonalds, best, mcdonalds, expe...
                              ...
1677    [mcdonalds, app, order, arrived, line, drive, ...
1693    [correct, order, filled, promptly, expecting, ...
1694    [wow, fantastic, eatery, high, quality, ive, e...
1704    [let, tell, eat, lot, mcchickens, best, ive, m...
1716    [entertaining, staff, ive, come, mcdees, servi...
Name: text, Length: 283, dtype: object
```

Now I create the Word2Vec model and train it:

```
model = gensim.models.Word2Vec(sentences=df, vector_size=200, window=10, min_count=1, workers=6)
model.train(df,total_examples=model.corpus_count,epochs=model.epochs)
print(model.wv.most_similar("service",topn=10))
```

What I dont understand is that the function most_similar() returns to me a lot of 0.99 of similarity.

```
[('like', 0.9999310970306396), ('mcdonalds', 0.9999251961708069), ('food', 0.9999234080314636), ('order', 0.999918520450592), ('fries', 0.9999175667762756), ('got', 0.999911367893219), ('window', 0.9999082088470459), ('way', 0.9999075531959534), ('it', 0.9999069571495056), ('meal', 0.9999067783355713)]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right that's not normal.

It is unlikely that your `df` is the proper format `Word2Vec` expects. It needs a re-iterable Python sequence, where each item is a *list* of *string tokens*.

Try displaying `next(iter(df))`, to see the 1st item in `df`, if iterated over as `Word2Vec` does. Does it look like a good piece of training data?

Separately regarding your code:

- `min_count=1` is always a bad idea with `Word2Vec` - rare words can't get good vectors but do, in aggregate, serve a lot like random noise making nearby words harder to train. Generally, the default `min_count=5` shouldn't be lowered unless you're sure that will help your results, because you can compare that value's effects versus lower values. And if it seems like too much of your vocabulary disappears because words don't appear even a measly 5 times, you likely have too little data for this data-hungry algorithm.
- Only 283 texts are unlikely to be enough training data unless each text has tens of thousands of tokens. (And even if it were possible to squeeze some results from this far-smaller-than-ideal corpus, you might need to shrink the `vector_size` and/or increase the `epochs` to get the most out of minimal data.
- If you supply a corpus to `sentences` in the `Word2Vec()` construction, you *don't* need to call `.train()`. It will have already automatically used that corpus fully as part of the constructor. (You only need to call the indepdendent, internal `.build_vocab()` & `.train()` steps if you *didn't* supply a corpus at construction-time.)

I highly recommend you enable logging to at least the `INFO` level for the relevant classes (either all Gensim or just `Word2Vec`). Then you'll see useful logging/progress info which, if you read over, will tend to reveal problems like the redundant second training here. (That redundant training *isn't* the cause of your main problem, though.)

Answer (score 0):

According to the [official doc](https://tedboy.github.io/nlps/generated/generated/gensim.models.Word2Vec.most_similar.html):

```
Find the top-N most similar words. ... 
This method computes cosine similarity between a simple mean of the projection weight 
vectors of the given words and the vectors for each word in the model. The method 
corresponds to the word-analogy and distance scripts in the original word2vec 
implementation. ...
```

Since you put this df as your sentence base in the param, gensim just calculates the analogy and distance of words in different sentences (dataframe rows). I'm not sure your dataframe contains "service", if yes, the result words are just words which have the closest values to "service" in their sentences.